# What is the name two mutually idempotent functions?

Tags: sets

To clarify, in haskell, there is an `ord` function that gives the byte integer of a character (i.e. `ord 'a'` yields `97`); and there is a `char` function that takes the byte integer of a character and returns the character (i.e. `char 97` yelds `'a'`.

What is the name of a collection of such functions? I'm not very mathematically literate (I'm working on it), but I found [semirings on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring). Do semirings provide an appropriate description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are known as *inverse functions*. For example, the mappings $x \mapsto 2x$ and $x \mapsto x/2$ are inverses of each other, as are $\exp$ and $\log$ (restricted to positive numbers), or $\sin$ (restricted to the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$) and $\arcsin$.

Comment: Ha! Of course. It's so obvious when you say it. Thanks